# Transitive dependencies with Gradle & OpenJFX

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, openjfx

I am in the process of setting up JavaFX-based project with Gradle 7.3.
The project has the following structure:

```
project/
├─ boot/
├─ gui/
├─ other_module1/
├─ other_moduleN/
```

All JavaFX related code belongs into the GUI module, while boot defines the entry point.

---

The `gui/build.gradle.kts` for the module GUI uses the OpenJFX plugin:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.10"
}

// ...

javafx {
    version = "17"
    modules("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
}
```

whereas the boot package only imports GUI:

```kotlin
plugins {
    application
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":gui"))
    implementation(project(":network"))
}

application {
    mainClass.set("project.boot.Boot")
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "project.boot.Boot"
    }
}
```

---

Using this setup, my project wont compile and crashes while working on boot:

```
error: cannot access Application
        Game.execute(args);
            ^
  class file for javafx.application.Application not found
```

This can be fixed by also applying the OpenJFX Plugin - the same way as seen above - to boot (`boot/build.gradle.kts`).

---

**QUESTION**:
How can I apply JavaFX transitively, so that it remains an implementation detail within the GUI module?

As I am new to Gradle and Java, I am probably missing something small yet crucial.

Also, I tried to read the docs, but the OpenJFX Plugin docs are quite outdated and often do not work as they are.

Comment: Does adding `configuration = "api"` to the `javafx { ... }` help?